# Linear Algebra: If a is a $5\times 8$ matrix which of the following are true?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Can someone tell me which of the following are correct and explain why that is true?  To me they are all false, but I am unsure.

[image]

Comment: so list out the reason you think they are false for each option

Comment: "To me they are all false" Are you saying choice E is false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of leading 1's in RREF tells us the rank of the matrix which is equal to the dimension of column space of $A$.

The column space is defined as the span of the columns of $A$, we should be able to find 3 columns of $A$ that span it if the dimension of column space is 3.

Comment: This makes perfect sense.  I was thinking it had to span R5x1, but it only has to span the column space.  gotcha